# WebStorm highlights CommonModule directives (empl: *ngIf, *ngFor) as they were not provided

Tags: angular, webstorm

I cannot find the exact problem. WebStorm highlights CommonModule directives even if the BrowserModule was provided. Below you can see my `app.module` and `app.component.html`. But it seems that everything is okay, because the app compiles correctly. There is no any problem highlighted in the Visual Studio Code.

If I point this error, it says:

> Property ngIf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template.

**app.module**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html** *(here I get this highlights)*

```html
<h1 *ngIf="true">Title</h1>
```

My packages:

```text
- @angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.0
- @angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.0
- @angular-devkit/core            16.1.0
- @angular-devkit/schematics      16.0.6
- @angular/cli                    16.0.6
- @schematics/angular             16.0.6
- rxjs                            7.8.1
- typescript                      5.0.4
```

I tried to invalidate WebStorm caches, also I've created a new application and checked if this highlights appears (same situation).

It makes me mad, please help me to figure out this question.

Comment: What is your WebStorm version?

Comment: @LazyOne, yesterday I find that lots of people has this problem and everything was solved after Webstorm updates (to 2023.2 EAP). So I find your comment useful. Thank you!

Comment: Accordingly to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-60191 it should work fine in **2023.1.2** as well (unless it's a different issue/ticket)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty easy :D I just has to **update Webstorm (to 2023.2 EAP
v)**

Answer (score 0):

The angular structural directives are in the angular common module so that is the one you need to import.

Comment: The BrowserModule exactly exports Common Module, nevertheless thank you for your assumption!